# What is the meaning, in tensor notation, of the dot-within-a-circle $\odot$? Usually shown as an exponent?

Tags: tensor-calculus, group-theory, notation, representation-theory, linear-algebra

This $\odot$ notation is e.g. used in this Phys.SE posts:

- [General relativity: Why don't these two differentials commute?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/323736/2451)
- [Why isn't there a second baryon octet?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/377417/2451)

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product_of_representations#The_symmetric_and_alternating_square).

Answer (score 3):

1. The notation $V\odot V$ means the symmetric [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product)$^1$ similar to that $V\wedge V$ means the antisymmetric tensor product.
2. This can be generalized to higher tensor powers. e.g.
   ${\rm Sym}^3V~\equiv~ V\odot V\odot V~\equiv~V^{\odot 3},$
   and
   $ \bigwedge{}^3V~\equiv~ V\wedge V\wedge V,$
   and so forth.

--

$^1$ The [tensor product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product) $V\otimes V$ is neither symmetric nor antisymmetric.

Comment: I believe, although I am not certain, that this answers my question...  The dot-within-a-circle is the symmetric tensor product, and the upside-down V, or lambda, is the antisymmetric tensor product...  Thank you!!       It's just that, on the, [Why isn't there a second baryon octet](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/61575/2451) page, the capital-lambda looked normal, while the dot-circle looked like an exponent of some sort...

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: @KurtHikes As a note, the upside-down V is usually referred to as *wedge*, which is reflected in the LaTeX/MathJax command `\wedge` $\rightarrow \wedge$.